# Setting env variable to a cron scheduled task using whenever gem

Tags: ruby, cron, rake-task, whenever

In my code below, I wanted to set few environment variables stored in a file. Am I missing something? Printing env in production after 'bundle exec whenever' does not show the environment variables set. Using whenever gem for a scheduled cron task and spent hours figuring this. Any other way can be suggested too.

```
every 1.day, :at => '2:30 am' do
  # Run shell script to assign variables and continue the rake task
  system "for line in `cat config/myEnvFile.env` ; do export $line ; done"
  rake "task:continue_doing_my_task"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `system` is not a whenever job type.  It's `Kernel.system`, which executes the String being passed to it when the whenever command is run, rather than converting that String to cron syntax.  It looks like what you really mean is:

   ```
   command "for line in `cat config/myEnvFile.env` ; do export $line ; done"
   # Note: command instead of system
   ```

   `command` is a built-in job type defined by whenever [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/v0.9.4/lib/whenever/setup.rb#L23).
2. Each line of code inside the `every`-block runs as it's own command.  If you run `whenever` (without any arguments, so it just displays what it *would* put in your crontab without actually modifying the crontab, and after making the correction I describe above), you'll see that the output is something like this:

   ```
   30 2 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'for line in `cat config/myEnvFile.env` ; do export $line ; done'
   30 2 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/project && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake task:continue_doing_my_task --silent > my_log_file.log 2&>1'
   ```

   Notice 2 issues:

   1. Firstly, these 2 commands have nothing to do with each other--they are run as 2 totally separate processes.
   2. The first one is running in cron's default directory, which is probably **not** where config/myEnvFile.env is located.

   To fix this, you need to merge everything into a single command.  By using whenever's `rake` job type, you **will** end up in the right directory, but you still to export all those variables somehow.

   One way to do this, is to rename the file `.ruby-env` and use rvm.  rvm, in addition to managing ruby versions for you, will automatically load all environment variables defined in `.ruby-env` when you enter the directory.

   If RVM is not an option for you, or you want something more lightweight, rename the file `.env` and use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).  Their README documents exactly how to use the gem, with or [without](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/tree/v2.1.0#sinatra-or-plain-ol-ruby) Rails.  Without Rails, it's this easy:

   - Add dotenv to your Gemfile
   - Make this change to your Rakefile:

     ```
     require 'dotenv/tasks' # 1. require this file
     namespace :task
       task continue_doing_my_task: :dotenv do # 2. make :dotenv a prerequisite for your task
     ```